# php GET requests and their subsequent use as a variable (in an SQL confdition)

Tags: php, mysql, select, get, where-clause

I have successfully extracted the correct data from my database during testing (its just a prototype - so yes I know its not secure SQL). The test SQL is

```
  $sql=
    SELECT *
    FROM jobcards
    WHERE jobnumber='$jobnumber'
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {loop}
```

The issue is the source of the data to which $jobnumber is set.

If during testing I set $jobnumber to the string Agen912-491 (implicitly) I get out of the database exactly what I should get out. However here is the problem.

I am clicking from a link on another page. The link creates the URL:-

```
   domain.php/jobcard.php?jobnumber=%20Agen912-491
```

which take me to the page on which the SQL query (and the output) resides. So on the page I set

```
    $jobnumber = $_GET["jobnumber"];
    echo $jobnumber;//testing
```

to request (and test) the jobnumber (passed from the link) that I need to insert into the WHERE condition. As expected the echo correctly returns Agen912-491. So exactly the same string (it seems) as the implicit value used succesfully in testing. All good so far.

However when I then set $jobnumber= $_GET["jobnumber"]; the database query fails to find any records. [In desperation I fudged the process so that the variable $jobnumber = $_SESSION ["jobnumber"]; (and ensured via an echo that $_session[] gave me Agent912-491). Now the database correctly returns the record again!

So for some reason the $*GET["jobnumber"]; statement when set to $jobnumber is failing [even though when it is echoed it returns the correct value that works implicity (and when set it via $s*[session]. So there is clearly an issue with a) requesting $_GET["jobnumber"]; b) setting it to the $jobnumber and then c) using that in the WHERE statement. Everything else works as does setting $jobnumber implicitly or via $_session.

I have an incline it might be something to do with santitising the $_GET result before using it. But that really is a guess and even if correct I dont know what exactly to try out.

Help would be really appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I see a urlencoded space in front of that value `jobnumber=%20Agen912-491 ` my guess is you don't expect that to be there. Remove it or `trim($_GET['jobnumber'])`

Comment: @user2755309, Then edit your question so that the second sentence does read like your comment

Comment: Thanks Crayon. Are you suggesting i try ?$jobnumber=trim($_GET['jobnumber']);

Comment: Well that depends.. is the value supposed to be `" Agen912-491"` (with a leading space) or `Agen912-491` (no leading space)?  If the latter, then no, do not `trim` it; your issue is something else. If the former, then I'd firstly suggest you look at what's putting the space there in the first place. Failing that, I suggest you trim the value before using it in your SQL query, yes.

Comment: I tried $jobnumber=trim($_GET['jobnumber']);

Comment: Thanks. I tried $jobnumber=trim($_GET['jobnumber']); I still get the exact same problem. $echoing $jobnumber after assigning it to trim($_GET['jobnumber']); gives me the correct number ie Agent912-491 but when $jobnumber is then assigned to WHERE it is not recognised so no record is returned.

Comment: However if I type in the $jobnumber=Agent912-491 it works fine and I get my record out. [Preversely the URL is usually minus the 20% but occasionally the 20% pops into the URL (but the process with or without the 20% and with or without TRIM fails if GET is used as the source of the variable--even though GET echos ok!!]. Mind blower this one is. ps...the value is supposed to be "Agen912-491" [ie no space].

Comment: Okay so I also notice that you say sometimes the value has **Agen** and sometimes you say it has **Agent** (with a "t").  Are both applicable? Perhaps you are missing a "t" in your url parameter value?

Comment: The beauty of the mysqli_ and PDO APIs is that they allow prepared statements. Really a shame then not to take advantage!

Comment: I think you have solved it Crayon. Here is the slightly adjusted syntax which worked. $jobnumber= trim($_GET["jobnumber"]); And this is the offending code that created the wretched invisible space in the first place. <a href=\"/selectfromjobcard_manager.php?jobnumber= ".$row["jobnumber"]."   \">   ".$row["jobnumber"]."   </a>.

Comment: And you know what. That was a lesson learnt the hard way. Thank you

Comment: @Strawberry while I agree with the sentiment, this issue has NOTHING to do with prepared statements

Comment: Ps the "t" was just a typo on here that's all...interesting the url doesnt always return  the % lead though. Maybe there is another surprise in store for me on this issue in the next hour or so ....

Comment: thanks Crayon! Really appreciated.